# Lattice theory of solution: Statistical mechanics derivation of mixing properties

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In lattice theory of ideal solutions, as outlined in Terrell L. Hill's "An Introduction to Statistical Thermodynamics" (1986), the canonical partition function becomes

$$
Q  = \left( q_Ae^{-cw_{AA}/2kT} \right)^{N_A} \left( q_B e^{-cw_{BB}/2kT} \right)^{N_B} \frac{(N_A + N_B)!}{N_A!N_B!}
$$

Where $M = N_A + N_B$ is the total number of lattice sites, and $q$ is the molecular partition function. I want to derive the expression for energy and entropy of mixing. I have that

\begin{align}
\Delta_{\text{mix}}U &= U_{AB} - U_A - U_B \\
\Delta_{\text{mix}}S &= S_{AB} - S_A - S_B
\end{align}

Further,

\begin{align}
U = kT^2\left( \frac{\partial \ln Q}{\partial T} \right)_{N,M}
\end{align}

Calculating $U_A$, $U_B$, $S_A$, and $S_B$ is just algebra, and should be fine. However, I'm not sure what exactly the terms $U_{AB}$ and $S_{AB}$ are. The book does not go into detail about this derivation, and I cannot find any information about it online.

Comment: Presumably that equation should be read, "The change in $U$ due to mixing is equal to the $U$ of the $AB$ system where both $A$ and $B$ are mixed minus the $U$ of the $A$ system before mixing, minus the $U$ of the $B$ system before mixing."

Comment: You're right, that leads to the correct expressions.